# Is there a way to connect through a proxy while using websocket in Rust?

Tags: websocket, rust, proxy, socks

With reqwest you can use a proxy server like this:

```
let client = reqwest::Client::builder()?
    .proxy(reqwest::Proxy::http("https://my.proxy.local:1080")?)
    .build()?;
```

I am using websocket like this:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;
extern crate websocket;

use websocket::Message;
use websocket::result::WebSocketError;
use websocket::{ClientBuilder, OwnedMessage};
use websocket::header::{Headers, Authorization, Basic};
use websocket::futures::{Future, Stream, Sink};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

const CONNECTION: &'static str = "wss://some.remote.host.example.org:443/";

let mut core = Core::new()?;
let client = ClientBuilder::new(CONNECTION)?
   .async_connect_secure(None)  
   .and_then(|(msg, _)| match msg {
       Some(OwnedMessage::Text(response_txt)) => Ok(response_txt),
       _ => Err(WebSocketError::ProtocolError(UNSUPPORTED_MSG_ERR)),
   });

let response_message = core.run(client)?;
```

Is there a way to use a https or socks proxy with websocket?

Comment: What happens when you set your env variable proxy ?

Comment: Which one? But yeah, I set them all, because I use curl, wget, git, node, composer etc behind proxy. 
Actually rust reqwest uses the system proxy somehow and I have to call .no_proxy() to prevent going through a proxy if connecting to local resources, but websocket does not.

Comment: If you set the system proxy and your websocket is not going through, maybe that your proxy was not configured to let websocket through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Proxy_traversal